# How to horizontally center all items in bulma navbar?

Tags: css, flexbox, bulma

By default bulma css framework left aligns all items in the navbar. However that's very inconvenient for big displays.

Having this html layout (as per bulma's documentation):

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navigation">
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <a class="navbar-item" href="http://localhost:8000">
          <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="50">
        </a>
        <a class="navbar-item" href="http://localhost:8000">Sitename</a>
        <a role="button" class="navbar-burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navMenu">
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-menu" id="navMenu">
        <div class="navbar-start">
          <a class="navbar-item" href="/link1.html">link 1</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="/link2.html">link 2</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="/link3.html">link 3</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="/link4.hmlt">link 4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

Produces:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Adding additional css:

```css
.navbar {
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Doesn't seem to be enough.

Jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/q6j9Lyf2/1/

Comment: `.navbar-menu {
     flex-grow: 0!important;
 }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your style written in `.navbar` class won't apply until unless you add `display: flex`

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

also you have to add

```
.navbar-menu {
    flex-grow: initial!important;
    flex-shrink: initial!important;
}
```

Don't like using `!important` write like this

```
.navbar .navbar-menu {
    flex-grow: initial;
    flex-shrink: initial;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working https://jsfiddle.net/q6j9Lyf2/2/ or did I miss something?

Comment: Updated the answer. We need to add !important

Comment: Thanks! I'm not a fan of using `!important` but this time around it seems to be required.

Comment: We could do that without important. Just we have to access it under parent classes.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

```css
.navbar{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```